# Dropdown в юнити только с множественным выбором

Tags: unity3d, dropdown

Как сделать в unity dropdown где можно будет возможность выбрать сразу несколько параметров(аналогично выпадающему списку LayerMask)
Нужно это в инспекторе а не в игре

Тоесть если enum позволяет сделать dropdown только с одним выбором, то что нужно использовать для создания dropdown с множественным выбором?

Comment: смотрите в сторону атрибута **[Flags]**

Comment: То что тебе нужно делается с помощью [Custom Editors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) через [ToggleGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.BeginToggleGroup.html)! Можно даже сделать сварачивающийся через [Foldout](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Foldout.html). А с записью через побитовый сдвиг потом работать будет не удобно и читаемость кода без написания отдельных методов с осмысленным неймингом по получению флагов, херовая. Инспектор вообще не должен диктовать классу, каким ему быть.

Answer (score -1):

Я нашел дополнение(плагин) для юнити - https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/naughtyattributes-129996

И в нём есть аттрибут EnumFlags - который позволяет сделать в инспекторе dropdown с несколькими выборами, при условии что enum записан через битовый сдвиг влево

Пример кода - https://dbrizov.github.io/na-docs/attributes/drawer_attributes/enum_flags.html

Дублирование кода с сайта -

```
public enum Direction
{
    None = 0,
    Right = 1 << 0,
    Left = 1 << 1,
    Up = 1 << 2,
    Down = 1 << 3
}

public class NaughtyComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [EnumFlags]
    public Direction flags;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пример кода, вероятно, стоило бы и процитировать. ведь: [ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)